# How to test received data equals content of json file - Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing

How would one test the received response data from a function equals the contents of a .json file?

For example:
I have a function that will fill in some json fields with the values passed to it, and I am wanting to test that this of course works correctly.

What I am thinking...

```
var firstName: string = 'Jim';
var lastName: string = 'Ross';
var jsonDataMaker: any = service.jsonifyData(firstName, lastName);

const expectedJson = require('./expectedJson.json');

expect(jsonDataMaker).toBe(expectedJson);
```

**expected.json**

```
{
   "user": {
      "firstName": "Jim",
      "lastName": "Ross"
   }
}
```

Any pointers would be great :-)

Comment: Change `toBe` to `toEqual` and you're more or less done.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense. Try posting some code of yours and the expected result if you can.